# Refresh canvas after deleting - Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

My problem is that when I consult an image from `D:/Folder/my_drawing.jpg` after "cleaning" the canvas, the canvas is dirty with the previous drawn images. The canvas is visually clear, but accumulates the former drawn image and the new one. The goal is make a Paint like program, that allows save draws and with a button that clean all the canvas.

The behaviour is as follow:
First I draw the curved line, after I clean the canvas, and after that, I draw the line, and when I consult the image, opening the file, the image is composed as shown below:

[image]

This is the code, in Python:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
class Paint(object):

    def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()        
            self.pen_button = self.use_pen

            self.save_button = Button(self.root, text='Save', command=self.Save)        
            self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=3)


            self.eraser_button = Button(self.root, text='Clean canvas', command=self.use_eraser)
            self.eraser_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

            self.c = Canvas(self.root, bg='white', width=600, height=600)        
            self.c.grid(row=1, columnspan=5) 

            self.setup()
            self.root.mainloop()

    def activate_button(self, some_button):        
            self.active_button = some_button
    def use_pen(self):
        self.activate_button(self.pen_button)


    def setup(self):
        self.path=''
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None
        self.image1 = Image.new("RGB",(600,600),'white')
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image1)
        self.active_button = self.pen_button

        self.c.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.paint)
        self.c.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.reset)     

    def use_eraser(self):       
            self.c.delete(ALL)   

    def Save(self):
            self.c.postscript(file="my_drawing.jpg", colormode='color')
            filename = "my_drawing.jpg"
            self.image1.save(filename)            

    def paint(self, event):        
        self.line_width = 2.0    
        paint_color = 'black'
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                               width=self.line_width, fill=paint_color, dash=(),capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
            self.draw.line([self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y], fill="black", width=5)

        self.old_x = event.x
        self.old_y = event.y

    def reset(self, event):
        self.old_x, self.old_y = None, None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Paint()
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please provide examples of any data or images that the program uses.

Comment: Sorry about that, now I added the part of code that was pending. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with this changes. I hope it serves to another with the same problem.

```
import io
    def Save(self):        
        ps=self.c.postscript(colormode='color')
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
        img.save('D:/Folder/my_drawing.jpg')

def paint(self, event):        
        self.line_width = 2.0    
        paint_color = self.color
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                               width=self.line_width, fill=paint_color, dash=(),
                               capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)        
        self.old_x = event.x
        self.old_y = event.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well..., you never actually display the image on the canvas.

In the function `paint()` you first draw a line segmant on the canvas, then you draw it in the image.

The function `use_eraser()` clears the canvas but does nothing with the image `self.image1`.

So, don't draw anything on the canvas but only on the image, and then display the image on the canvas. I have not worked much with `PIL` but I should think the image display will update automatically as you draw on it.